# Why isn't my carouFredSel working?

Tags: jquery, carousel, caroufredsel

It works fine when I test it, but when I load it into the (yes, extremely clunky and awful) CMS it stops working. Normally I can figure out what css nonsense the cms is putting in the way, but I've tried for hours and I've gone nuts.

http://facewebsites.com/testpage/

Comment: is the given solution fixed your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You referred jquery core library `<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>` at the end of the page and `js/common.js` file in the `head` section. Please note that the jquery core library should needed to be included at first before calling any other jquery related libraries and custom script.

Please move `js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js` reference to the header section. Also, use developer tools (in chrome and IE, hit F12 key) in any browsers to see and inspect whether there is any error in your script.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't the problem. jquery-1.7.1.min.js is referenced in the header. Also, even if I move it to the very top of the header, CaroFedSel still doesn;t work.

Comment: did you upload the latest changed page?

Comment: I can see these dom errors. fix all those to get the carousel worked. Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined validate.js:329
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (index):765
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined (index):833
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: form[@name="frmLogin"] :input[@type="text"] jquery-1.7.1.min.js:4
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: $ is not defined means you've missed the jquery core library.